# Primefaces p:rowExpansion shows random data

Tags: jsf, primefaces, primefaces-datatable

I implemented the <p:rowExpansion> from PF in my HTML, as seen below.

```
<p:column style="width:16px">
  <p:rowToggler />
</p:column>  
  
<p:column headerText="Content 1" sortBy="#{portview.port_comment}">
  <h:outputText value="#{contentbean.content1}" />
</p:column>

<p:rowExpansion>
  <p:panelGrid columns="2" columnClasses="label,value" style="width:50%">
    <h:outputText value="Label:" />
    <h:outputText value="#{portview.port_comment}" />
  </p:panelGrid>
</p:rowExpansion>
```

Yet, the data shown in the expansion does not fit the row it was issued from and in the PF website I can't find any clues on how to solve this.

**Q: What should I do here?**

UPDATE:

I use version 8.0 of Primefaces. The outcome looks like this...

[image: outcome screenshot]

The data in the expansion shows just any value from the view.

Here's my bean behind the html...

```
@Named(value = "vb")
@ViewScoped
public class ViewBean implements Serializable {

@Inject
private ViewHandler vh;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
}

public List<PortView> getPVList() {
    return vh.getPortViewList();
}
```

And the `ViewHandler` looks like this...

```
@Stateless
public class ViewHandler {

public List<PortView> getPortViewList() {
    List<PortView> pvlist = em.createQuery("SELECT v FROM PortView v", PortView.class).getResultList();
    return pvlist;
}
```

Comment: Primefaces version? Can you post a screenshot of your result?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]